# Discover Relationships and Node labels in an existing Neo4j dataset

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j but am exploring an existing dataset at work. I'm having trouble discovering the relationships through the Neo4j desktop tool.

Does Cypher support queries that could answer the following?

1. List all relationships
2. For every relationship, list types of nodes are on either side
3. For given nodes, list relationships that exist on them

Comment: To the people who downvoted and closed this question: can you explain why? I think you may have misunderstood what I'm asking. Neo4j is an open source widely used technology. I am not asking questions specific to my use case. It's a general question about Neo4j's capabilities, and the helpful answer below is potentially useful for any Neo4j users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TYPE() function will give you the type for a relationship. To see a count of relationships by type, run this query.

```
MATCH ()-[r]->()
RETURN TYPE(r) AS relationshipType, COUNT(*) AS relationshipCount
```

The LABELS() function will give you the labels on a node. To see the types of nodes on each side of a relationship, run this query.

```
MATCH (s)-[r]->(e)
RETURN labels(s) AS startLabels, 
TYPE(r) AS relationshipType,
LABELS(e) AS endLabels,
COUNT(*) AS relationshipCount
```

To see a count of the relationship types connected to nodes with a given label, run this query, substituting your label name for "myLabel."

```
MATCH (s:myLabel)-[r]-()
RETURN TYPE(r) AS relationshipType,
COUNT(*) AS relationshipCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of this data is stored in the counts store. While you can issue Cypher queries that can take advantage of this, the best way to get a view of all of that info is by dumping the counts store data.

If you have APOC Procedures installed you can use:

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats()
```

If not, then you can use:

```
CALL db.stats.retrieve('GRAPH COUNTS')
```

You can also see a graph version of the labels and relationships in your graph with:

```
CALL apoc.meta.graph()
```

or, if without APOC, then:

```
CALL db.schema.visualization()
```

Comment: Thanks! `CALL apoc.meta.graph()` was particularly helpful.